# How to work correctly airflow schedule_interval

Tags: airflow

I want to try to use Airflow instead of Cron.
But schedule_interval doesn't work as I expected.

I wrote the python code like below.
And in my understanding, Airflow should have ran on "2016/03/30 8:15:00" but it didn't work at that time.

If I changed it like this "'schedule_interval': timedelta(minutes = 5)", it worked correctly, I think.

The "notice_slack.sh" is just to call slack api to my channels.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 3, 29, 8, 15),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='notice_slack',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=1))

# cmd file name
CMD = '/tmp/notice_slack.sh'

run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_transport', bash_command=CMD, dag=dag)
```

I want to run some of my scripts at specific time every day like this cron setting.

```
15 08 * * * bash /tmp/notice_slack.sh
```

I have read the document [Scheduling & Triggers](http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/scheduler.html), and I know it's a little bit different cron.
So I attempt to arrange at "start_date" and "schedule_interval" settings.

Does anyone know what should I do ?

> airflow version
>
> INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
>
> v1.7.0
>
> amazon-linux-ami/2015.09-release-notes

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 3, 29),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='notice_slack',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="15 08 * * *",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=1))

# cmd file name
CMD = 'bash /tmp/notice_slack.sh'

run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_transport', bash_command=CMD, dag=dag)
```

`start_date` (datetime) – The start_date for the task, determines the execution_date for the first task instance. The best practice is to have the start_date rounded to your DAG’s schedule_interval.

`schedule_interval` (datetime.timedelta or dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta or str that acts as a cron expression) – Defines how often that DAG runs, this timedelta object gets added to your latest task instance’s execution_date to figure out the next schedule.

Simply configuring the `schedule_interval` and `bash_command` as the same in your cron setting is okay.

Comment: Should be worth noting that the `execution_date` will be the start of the interval which just ended. So with this setup, the first run will be dated `2016 03 29T08:15:00.000` in the scheduled `dag_run` which is the what the passed in `execution_date` will be, but it will trigger this run a little bit after `2016 03 30T08:15:00` which is when the full interval from the `execution_date` has passed.

Answer (score 18):

Airflow will start your DAG when the 2016/03/30 8:15:00 + schedule interval (daily) is passed. So your DAG will run on 2016/03/31 8:15:00.

You can check the [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html)

Comment: `@daily` is a shortcut for `0 0 * * *` if I read the docs correctly, meaning it would run at midnight; right?

Comment: @dlamblin your assumption is correct. first 0 is for 0th minute of the day. Second 0 is for 0th hour of the day. [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression)

Comment: This answer is not correct. `start_date` parameter is just a date-time after wich DAG runs would be started. But real schedule contain parameter `schedule_interval`. `@daily` value say that DAG have to run at midnight. To run at 08:15 every day: `schedule_interval='15 08 * * *'`.

Answer (score 15):

First, your start date should be in the past -
Instead of `'start_date': datetime(2016, 3, 29, 8, 15)`
Would you try `'start_date': datetime(2016, 2, 29, 8, 15)`

and apply 'catchup':False to prevent backfills - unless this was something you wanted to do.

From Airflow documentation -
The Airflow scheduler triggers the task soon after the start_date + schedule_interval is passed.

The schedule interval can be supplied as a cron -
If you want to run it everyday at 8:15 AM, the expression would be - ****'15 8 * * *'****

If you want to run it only on Oct 31st at 8:15 AM, the expression would be - ****'15 8 31 10 *'****

To supply this, `'schedule_inteval':'15 8 * * *'` in your Dag property

You can figure this out more from https://crontab.guru/

Alternatively, there are Airflow presets -
[image]

If any of these meet your requirements, it would be simply, `'schedule_interval':'@hourly'`

Lastly, you can also apply the schedule as python timedelta object e.g. for 12 PM

`'schedule_interval': timedelta(hours=12)`

Comment: The catch up mechanism is a good way to ensure the run which does not happen on the specified timing can be re run to fill it up.

Answer (score 1):

With the example you've given `@daily` will run your job after it passes midnight. You might try changing it either to `timedelta(days=1)` which is relative to your fixed `start_date` that includes 08:15.
Or you could use a cron spec for the `schedule_interval='15 08 * * *'` in which case any start date prior to 8:15 on the day BEFORE the day you wanted the first run would work.

Note that `depends_on_past: False` is already the default, and you may have confused its behavior with `catchup=false` in the DAG parameters, which would avoid making past runs for time between the start date and now where the DAG schedule interval would have run.