# Reset airflow DAG execution time

Tags: python, etl, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Currently I have a dag that's scheduled `@daily` and normally should be triggered just after midnight to run on the previous day's data.

Somehow, it has now started to run at 11:30AM, due to a run having issues in the past and being restarted at that time manually. Now it always triggers at that time. This, of course, is due to the scheduling algorithm triggering it one day after the last execution time.

However, running at 1130am is not exactly wanted. I'd like to be able to somehow have the DAG start up at midnight.

What are my options? I can always change the name, but is there a way that I can script easily if/when this happens in the future?

Airflow 1.8

DAG code:

```
dag = DAG('my_dag_v5',
          catchup=False,
          default_args=args, 
          start_date=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 30), 
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          max_active_runs=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, despite my best efforts at using the other answers, the only consistent way I've found to get airflow to *reset* execution times without risking database/scheduler strangeness is to rename the DAG itself.

The scheduler algorithm will compute the next execution time from the previous execution time + the scheduler delay.

If this changes, and the other answer works, I'll accept that, as it is what I would expect to work, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

change `schedule_interval='@daily'` to `schedule_interval='0 0 * * *'`

also change your start date from `start_date=datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 30, 4, 0)` to `start_date=datetime(2018, 1, 30)`.

`start_date` (datetime) – The start_date for the task, determines the execution_date for the first task instance. The best practice is to have the start_date rounded to your DAG’s schedule_interval.

`schedule_interval`- Defines how often that DAG runs, this timedelta object gets added to your latest task instance’s execution_date to figure out the next schedule.

This will make it run daily at midnight using CRON format.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) `'@daily'` and `'0 0 * * *'` are identical. Can you explain more how this would change the trigger time if the last execution time was at 11:30AM?

Comment: I've changed the cron expression to the explicit one, and due to the [scheduling algorithm](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/c26c56487649f8d912c20ebf7aec1677e9996ea4/airflow/jobs.py#L891) jobs are still only triggered at 11:30.

Comment: @nimish, you are correct that they should be identical (as stated in the docs). I believe they were not identical with it not starting at midnight due to you stating the hour and minute in your `start_date`. Please review my modified answer as I changed your `start_date` arg as well. This should hopefully fix your issues. Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298756/how-to-work-correctly-airflow-schedule-interval as a reference material.

Comment: Ah yes. I've applied that change, however it does not actually start at midnight -- it starts 24hrs after the last execution time (1130) -- changing the start_date doesn't change the scheduler for an ongoing dag (And can cause weirdness, which I want to avoid but not necessarily by changing the DAG name)

Comment: I guess what this answer doesn't address is that changing the start_date and scheduling_interval (from the symbolic to the cron string) doesn't affect anything with how the scheduler triggers the next DagRun when the previous DagRun was scheduled at an off-hour.