# How to control first run for Scheduled DAGs with non-standard schedule_interval

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am having issues scheduling my DAG runs properly, especially in terms of `schedule_interval` & `start_date`.

Airflow's default behavior doesn't suit my use case, wherein if I set an arbitrarily early date for `start_date`, airflow will always trigger the initial run outside the "intuitive" first schedule (e.g. if I set my `schedule_interval` to run at 12AM every Wednesday & Friday, and I created this DAG on a Monday with an arbitrarily early date many weeks back, there is a cron run at the exact instance the DAG is created in the Monday, which I do not want).

Understand from reference that the scheduled run will happen after 1 `scheduled_interval` cycle. While I have taken reference to [How to work correctly airflow schedule_interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298756/how-to-work-correctly-airflow-schedule-interval) & https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.6/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup, they generally show examples related to regular intervals (e.g. hourly, daily, monthly, etc.).

However, in my scenario, I have a `schedule_interval` of `0 16 * * 1,2,0` & `0 16 * * 1,3,5`. As the intervals between runs are irregular, how do I set my `start_date` such that:

- The first run happens exactly on the next datetime when it is "intuitive" to run? e.g.

  1. if I create these 2 DAGs on a Saturday, I would want my DAGs to make their first run at 1600h on Sunday & Monday respectively
  2. if I create these 2 DAGs on Monday 1700h, I would want my DAGs to make their first run at 1600h on Tuesday & Wednesday respectively

Comment: When a DAG Runs is triggered is not dependent on when you create the DAG and can be fully managed by `start_date`, `schedule_interval` and `catch_up`. I can recommend to also have a look [here](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-tasks/). It looks like that you should set `catchup=false` and `start_date` to a future date if you don't want to execute it right away.